# operator== and explicit constructor in boost::detail::atomic_count?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, g++

I found that boost::detail::atomic_count doesn't have the declaration and definition for operator==().

So if I have the following:

`boost::detail::atomic_count i(0);
if (i == 0) {
// do something
}`

Questions

1. Since boost::detail::atomic_count has an explicit constructor, it seems like the 0 in the if-statement won't be used as an parameter of the constructor?
2. There is no operator== defined and declared; how does the compiler compare i to zero?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.  The code is compiled and run fine with gcc 4.6.2 and boost 1.47. on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the sourcecode](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/atomic_count_gcc_x86.hpp) reveals that `boost::detail::atomic_count` has an implicit conversion to `long`, which is used for the equality comparison.

Comment: Argh, interesting.  Thanks!